# C++ cannot decode backtrace

Tags: c++, linux, centos

I have set up `backstrace_symbols` on my script using:

```
void handler(int sig) {
    void *array[20];
    size_t size;
    char **strings;
    size_t  i;

    size = backtrace(array, 20);
    strings = backtrace_symbols(array,size);

    tracelog.open("/var/log/safesquid/safesquid/debug/trace.log", ios::app);
    tracelog << sig << endl;
    for (i=0; i<size; i++)
        tracelog << strings[i] << endl;

    free(strings);

    exit(1);
}
```

In the main function, it is called it using

```
signal(SIGSEGV, handler);
```

**Backtrace:**

```
11
/opt/scripts/cplusconnector(_Z7handleri+0x2b) [0x40233b]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x32920) [0x7fe7b503c920]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x131b5f) [0x7fe7b513bb5f]
/opt/scripts/cplusconnector(main+0x163) [0x4035c3]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd) [0x7fe7b5028cdd]
/opt/scripts/cplusconnector() [0x402199]
11
/opt/scripts/cplusconnector(_Z7handleri+0x2b) [0x40233b]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x32920) [0x7fd9db71a920]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x131b5f) [0x7fd9db819b5f]
/opt/scripts/cplusconnector(main+0x163) [0x4035c3]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd) [0x7fd9db706cdd]
/opt/scripts/cplusconnector() [0x402199]

[root@server dev]# addr2line -e test-unstrippped 0x402199 0x7f1999f16cdd 0x4035c3
??:0
??:0
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/basic_string.h:975
```

Where could the problem be and why does running the program result in a [segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)?

**update:**

it was compiled using these options

```
g++ cplusconnector-k.cpp -g -rdynamic -O2 -I/usr/include/mysql -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlcppconn -o test  `mysql_config --cflags --libs`
```

**update:**

i removed the optimization, and tried resolving the symbol using add2line from the backtrace, and it pointed to this line in code..

```
/opt/webcache/scripts/cplusconnector(_Z7handleri+0x25) [0x401d49]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x32920) [0x7f6ad974b920]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x131b5f) [0x7f6ad984ab5f]
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSsaSEPKc+0x1c) [0x7f6ad9dcd12c]
/opt/webcache/scripts/cplusconnector(main+0x12b) [0x4027ae]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd) [0x7f6ad9737cdd]
/opt/webcache/scripts/cplusconnector() [0x401c69]


[root@server dev]# addr2line -e test 0x401d49 0x7f6ad974b920 0x7f6ad984ab5f 0x7f6ad9dcd12c 0x4027ae 0x7f6ad9737cdd 0x401c69
/usr/local/dev/cplusconnector-k.cpp:42
??:0
??:0
??:0
/usr/local/dev/cplusconnector-k.cpp:138
??:0
??:0
```

line: 42 is outside the main function and is global:

```
ofstream httplog;
```

line:138 is inside the main function:

```
    if (std::string::npos != host.find(string("1.0.0.1"))){
          return 0;
       }
```

any ideas??

Comment: If you build with debugging symbols (give GCC the `-g` command-line option), then you should see filenames and line numbers in the backtrace. That will tell you which line of `main` calls the library function that's crashing. Running the code under a debugger (e.g. `gdb`), or enabling core dumps (`ulimit -c unlimited`) and examining the result in a debugger (`gdb my_program core`), might give you more information such as the values of variables at the time.

Comment: i have tried gdb, and also compiled it using the -g flag, the application gives no segfault when run from command line..and gdb is clean, its only when the proxy runs this script,gives a segfault...

Comment: @krisdigitx: Also, make sure the program you're debugging was compiled without optimisation (`-O0`), otherwise function inlining and other code transformations can make the backtrace rather unhelpful.

Answer (score 2):

To debug your program, you could enable [core](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/core.5.html) dumping (using the [setrlimit(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit) syscall, often thru the [ulimit](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_ulimit.htm) bash builtin). Then, run `gdb` with the program and the core dump.

As for why the `backtrace_symbols` is giving you such names, it is because of [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling). See also [this](http://mykospark.net/2009/09/runtime-backtrace-in-c-with-name-demangling/).

Consider also using Ian Taylor's [libbacktrace](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace) (integrated into recent versions of GCC, e.g. GCC 6 and above). Compile your code with `-g` (and perhaps also some optimization flag like `-O`)

Comment: i have tried gdb, and also compiled it using the -g flag, the application gives no segfault when run from command line..and gdb is clean, its only when the proxy runs this script,gives a segfault...

Answer (score 2):

I see there is indeed a good reason to use free()

For the name mangling use [abi::__cxa_demangle](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html).

Comment: `backtrace_symbols` returns a `malloc`ed array, so `free` is the right thing to use here.

Comment: @MikeSeymour yeah i relised my mistake a few seconds too late it seems

Answer (score 1):

backtrace() cannot be called from signal handlers.

There is a (short) list of methods that may be called from signal handlers.
I am too lazy too Google for it now though